# How to add op_tags to AssetsDefinitions after it has been defined

Tags: dagster

I can define an asset with op_tags, like

```py
@asset(op_tags={"model": "lgbm"})
def model():
    return MODEL
```

but I would like to use decorators to update/modify an assets tag, like

```py
@add_resources_to_op_tags
@add_owner_to_op_tags
@asset(op_tags={"model": "lgbm"})
def model():
    return MODEL
```

I have tried updating the `asset.node_def.tags` attribute, but it is a ReadOnlyDict. Setting it is also not allowed.

Doing asset.node_def._tags = new_tags seems to work, but I wonder if it could have unpredicted side effects, since the tags are defined in multiple attributes inside the asset.